# How can I correctly recycle bitmaps inside a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, bitmap

I have an app that contains a few fragments and in one of them
I have a custom view where I create a couple of bitmaps to draw on them.

Well the problem is:
When I exchange fragments everything is ok until I get to the one where the custom view is in. The problem is that when I select the fragment(that has the CustomView) again and again the RAM increases and then the app crashes.

I have checked the way in which the bitmaps get created and recycled and I can not find the solution.

code:

```
private Bitmap getCircle() {

    if (mDstBitmap == null) {
        mDstBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mWidth, mHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        c = new Canvas(mDstBitmap);
        c.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        p.setColor(Color.RED);
        c.drawOval(new RectF(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight), p);
    }

    return mDstBitmap;
}



@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    int viewWidthHalf = getWidth() / 2;
    int viewHeightHalf = getHeight() / 2;

    float radius = 0.0f;
    if (viewWidthHalf > viewHeightHalf)
        radius = (viewHeightHalf / 2);
    else
        radius = (viewWidthHalf / 2);


    circle = getCircle();

    canvas.drawBitmap(circle, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

}
```

I'm thinking in something like this, but it's not working:

```
@Override
protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    delete();
}


public void delete(){
    if (mDstBitmap != null) {
        mDstBitmap.recycle();
    }

    if (linesBitmap != null) {
        linesBitmap.recycle();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move your delete function to `onDestroy`. Even better, move it to `onPause`, but make sure to set the bitmap variables to null, so they get recreated if needed.
I hope there is more to the bitmap you are drawing, for as it is, there is no reason you don't paint it to canvas on the `onDraw` call, and skip creating the bitmap.